# Getting 403 error|"Attention Required!" Captcha when trying to scrape

Tags: web-scraping, recaptcha, captcha, cloudflare

I looked at the robots.txt file of a website and got the sitemap from there.
I want to scrape it but get a 403 error (urlopen) or this html response (when using curl)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Attention Required! | Cloudflare</title>
<meta name="captcha-bypass" id="captcha-bypass" />
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" /><![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">body{margin:0;padding:0}</style>


<!--[if gte IE 10]><!--><script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/zepto.min.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 10]><!--><script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/cf.common.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->




</head>
<body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="cf-error-details-wrapper">
      <div class="cf-wrapper cf-header cf-error-overview">
        <h1 data-translate="challenge_headline">One more step</h1>
        <h2 class="cf-subheadline"><span data-translate="complete_sec_check">Please complete the security check to access</span> www.idrivecertified.com</h2>
      </div><!-- /.header -->

      <div class="cf-section cf-highlight cf-captcha-container">
        <div class="cf-wrapper">
          <div class="cf-columns two">
            <div class="cf-column">

              <div class="cf-highlight-inverse cf-form-stacked">
                <form class="challenge-form" id="challenge-form" action="/cdn-cgi/l/chk_captcha" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="s" value="6bfef707b3cd0948ac32f5cdd799fde999bb502a-1551464417-1800-AXystx0zL4isQ7fLSJlI8C9UU2+0nm5RfJXpsQ+WZ7ndOaHokzltGw4sOmwwULEx+KfuILnP+wt/6CO90eEzOUBo6YPJqcQHME8FiR79h/JAqHGZibPvK4yS15wpCQVuLw=="></input>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/cf.challenge.js" data-type="normal"  data-ray="4b0d24defd87ccd0" async data-sitekey="6LfBixYUAAAAABhdHynFUIMA_sa4s-XsJvnjtgB0"></script>
  <div class="g-recaptcha"></div>
  <noscript id="cf-captcha-bookmark" class="cf-captcha-info">
    <div><div style="width: 302px">
      <div>
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k=6LfBixYUAAAAABhdHynFUIMA_sa4s-XsJvnjtgB0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 302px; height:422px; border-style: none;"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 300px; border-style: none; bottom: 12px; left: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; right: 25px; background: #f9f9f9; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; border-radius: 3px;">
        <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
      </div>
    </div></div>
  </noscript>
</form>


              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="cf-column">
              <div class="cf-screenshot-container">

                <span class="cf-no-screenshot"></span>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.columns -->
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.captcha-container -->

      <div class="cf-section cf-wrapper">
        <div class="cf-columns two">
          <div class="cf-column">
            <h2 data-translate="why_captcha_headline">Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA?</h2>

            <p data-translate="why_captcha_detail">Completing the CAPTCHA proves you are a human and gives you temporary access to the web property.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="cf-column">
            <h2 data-translate="resolve_captcha_headline">What can I do to prevent this in the future?</h2>


            <p data-translate="resolve_captcha_antivirus">If you are on a personal connection, like at home, you can run an anti-virus scan on your device to make sure it is not infected with malware.</p>

            <p data-translate="resolve_captcha_network">If you are at an office or shared network, you can ask the network administrator to run a scan across the network looking for misconfigured or infected devices.</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.section -->


      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper">
  <p>
    <span class="cf-footer-item">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong>4b0d24defd87ccd0</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator">&bull;</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item"><span>Your IP</span>: 2604:2000:f684:8d00:2ca1:a9b9:1950:7b53</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator">&bull;</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=error_footer" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>

  </p>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
  window._cf_translation = {};


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When i make a request from chrome I can see the page and so i copied the request from the network tab as curl and it does in fact work. So i tried setting the headers of my request to be like the ones from the successful curl request, but i still get a 403 error. Any ideas on how to proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

This will result in a forbidden status code (HTTP error 403) which means the server will not fulfill your request despite understanding the response. You will definitely get this error if you try scrape a lot of the more popular websites which will have security features to prevent bots.

if you are using request try to add this :

```
html_data = requests.get(BASE_URL,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).content
```